# NumPy: создание двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы, машинное-обучение, numpy

Я только начал изучать `NumPy`. Хочу уточнить:

```
b = np.array([[1.5, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

это есть создание двумерного массива, где b[0][0] = 1.5, b[1][0] = 4 и т.д.?

Comment: всё верно , тебе скинуть что посмотреть для изучения ML ?

Comment: Был бы благодарен, а то я купил "Введение в машинное обучению с помощью Python, Андреас Мюллер" и тут с первых страниц такие определения пошли, что боюсь мотивацию убьет.

Comment: Это да , ещё с матаном немного повозиться придётся

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgGADKKGalfwSNbpSyM5ryg/feed

Comment: Да конечно, я знал на что иду). Я люблю математику и увлекаюсь статистикой.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg   это препроцессинга данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

всё верно , тебе скинуть что посмотреть для изучения ML ?

Comment: Был бы благодарен, а то я купил "Введение в машинное обучению с помощью Python, Андреас Мюллер" и тут с первых страниц такие определения пошли, что боюсь мотивацию убьет.

Comment: Это да , ещё с матаном немного повозиться придётся

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgGADKKGalfwSNbpSyM5ryg/feed

Comment: Да конечно, я знал на что иду). Я люблю математику и увлекаюсь статистикой.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg   это препроцессинга данных

Answer (score 3):

**все** элементы матрицы `b` будут иметь тип данных `float` (скорее всего `float64`), т.к. один элемент - `1.5` типа `float`.

`float` - более "сильный" тип по сравнению с `int`, т.е. значение типа `int` (имеются в виду типы данных Numpy, а не Python `int` с неограниченной точностью) можно преобразовать во `float` без потери точности (информации), а обратно нет:

```
In [56]: b
Out[56]:
array([[1.5, 2. , 3. ],
       [4. , 5. , 6. ]])

In [57]: b.dtype
Out[57]: dtype('float64')
```

Индексация в Numpy гораздо более "продвинутая" по сравнению со стандартными питоновскими списками:

```
In [58]: b[1,0]
Out[58]: 4.0
```

здесь перед запятой это индекс(ы) элементов по первому измерению / оси (строки в случае `2D array`), после запятой по второму измерению (столбцы для 2D array).

Вот более интересные случаи:

```
In [67]: a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)

In [68]: a
Out[68]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [69]: a[:, 1]
Out[69]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10])

In [70]: a[:, 2]
Out[70]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])

In [71]: a[2, :]
Out[71]: array([6, 7, 8])

In [72]: a[[1,2], :]
Out[72]:
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

[Официальная документация](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)